# Finding all legal subsets. Backtrack Algorithm ? Dynamic Programming?

Tags: subset, dynamic-programming, backtracking

I am confused about the implementation of the following problem.
I have a bag of items, and a bag of rules specifying which items could be grouped together.

```
Items [1,2,3]
Rules [{1,2}, {3}, {1,3}, {2}, {1}, {1,2,3,4,5}]

Example output
[[{1,2},{3}], [{1,3}, {2}], [{1},{2},{3}]]
```

I am not sure what's a decent implementation. And what do you call this type of problem?

This is similar to parsing, which used CYK algorithm. For example if you have a sentence for Context-Free Grammar "I love you", it could follow rules {VP --> Love You, PRON --> I} and be grouped together. However, in this case, order matters. You cannot group "I" together with "you" since they are not adjacent. But in my case, this is possible, like {1,3} is grouped together.

Thank you very much

Comment: Please elaborate on the rules you have in your rules bag. Also explain about the numbers `3`, `4` and `5`, as there are no corresponding items in the items bag.

Comment: I've edited the question, we are finding legal subsets based on the given list of items. Since there are indices without corresponding items in the items bag, this rule cannot be used.